34 charges and 34 times guilty beyond reasonable doubt
Donald Trump had 34 charges against him and was found guilty beyond reasonable doubt in each single case. Is that normal or unusual? You would think that some charges have more and some have less evidence. So did the prosecutor not charge him with things where he thought Trump was likely guilty, but not clearly enough that there couldn't have been reasonable doubt, to avoid any "not guilty" judgement? Or did the jury argue like "we found him guilty 31 times, so he is probably guilty of charge #32, #33 and #34 as well"? Or was it actually that the prosecutor found 34 cases to answer where guilt was clear, and not a case #35 that might or might not have ended with "guilty"?
(From distant memory, around the time of the OJ Simpson trial, some guy shot and killed 16 people on a train, got 16 charges each for 1st degree murder, 2nd degree murder, and manslaughter, got 32 not guilty and 16 guilty verdicts, for a mixture of the three possible charges. So it would be absolutely possible to have multiple charges with different outcome in the same trial).

My understanding is that most of the doubt that the defence suggested, Cohen secretly paid off daniels, Trump did not have affair, Trump bought the story to protect his family and Cohen was paid off for doing legal work in 2017 would have applied to all 34 charges, so if their was doubt for one there would have been doubt for all.

If the whole scheme is criminal and there are multiple line items - why are you surprised that each line item is deemed criminal?

For the "related" case you called: He was charged with 3 alternative verdicts for each case, so there could be at most 16 guilty charges, as you can't both murder 1st, 2nd and manslaughter a person.

The vast majority of charges that go to a jury across the board result in guilty verdicts.

In 2022, 230 (16%) of the 1475 federal criminal jury trials resulted in acquittal.
In 2020, 78 (19%) of the 411 criminal trials in New York state superior court resulted in acquittal of all charges.
(I invite edits or comments to bring more specificity to these figures: isolating jury trials from bench trials in New York, information about acquittals or convictions on only a subset of the charges, etc.)

This is largely a function of prosecutorial discretion and the selection of strong cases. But it is not that uncommon that a jury only find the accused guilty on a subset of counts.
However, in this case, there was quite a bit of correlation in the evidence between the counts.
In the particular charges against Mr. Trump, there was near no question that the documents were what they were.
The issues surrounded intention. Jurors were instructed to consider each count on its own and were reminded that they needed to be convinced beyond a reasonable doubt about any count that they were going to convict on. They are not to find that the accused is more likely to be guilty of count 34 because they found the accused guilty of counts 1–33. But they can rely on the same reasoning or kinds of evidence that convinced them of counts 1–33 to also lead them to a guilty verdict on count 34.
In this case, it is understandable that the evidence probative of intention with respect to some counts would also be probative of intention respect to other counts.

FWIW, the criminal cases in the U.S. federal courts are not representative of criminal cases in the U.S. (e.g. they also have a far higher percentage of bench trials), and the U.S. Justice Department has the luxury of only bringing solid cases and leaving closer cases to state court prosecutors. Only 2% of federal criminal case are tried. https://www.pewresearch.org/short-reads/2019/06/11/only-2-of-federal-criminal-defendants-go-to-trial-and-most-who-do-are-found-guilty/ The state court conviction rate is 75%-85% but is as low as 59% in FL. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conviction_rate

"This is largely a function of prosecutorial discretion and the selection of strong cases." Another factor is that if someone qualifies for a public defender (as most criminal defendants do) there is little downside to taking a weak case to trial because the defendant isn't paying for their legal fees. In theory, if prosecutors and defendants were equally like to reach plea bargains in close cases, you'd expect a 50% conviction rate, since very strong cases and very weak cases wouldn't go to trial.

@ohwilleke, you need to look at the benefits as well: the benefit to a defendant of going to court with a poor chance of winning is much higher than it is for a prosecutor, so you'd expect the balance to shift away from 50%.

From CBS News

Each of the 34 charges against Trump corresponded to a check, invoice and voucher generated to reimburse Cohen. The prosecution laid out the charges in a chart that jurors saw several times during the trial

So there weren't really 34 independent crimes being committed. There was one big crime, but each reimbursement of Cohen was a separate falsified record.
The prosecution was presumably careful to only include those reimbursements that could be directly linked to this conspiracy. So there's little reason for the jury to believe that some of them had more doubt than others.
This is similar to bringing multiple counts against a mass shooter. If someone shoots wildly into a crowd of random people, there will be a count of murder for each person who died. But in most cases there will be little reason to believe that some were more doubtful than others. However, if the crowd included a specific intended target, while others were collateral damage, there might be different degrees of the charges.
